# csnameの挙動について

Tags: tex

LaTeX（TeX Live 2018）の環境で、`\csname`を用いてコントロールシーケンストークンを動的に作成したいと考えていますが、思った通りに動作しません。

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\def\anaconda{OK}
\def\a{a}
% 下記のすべてsnakeと出力させたい
1. \csname anaconda \endcsname \\ % OKと出力されない
2. \csname anacond\a \endcsname \\ % OKと出力される
3. \csname \a naconda \endcsname \\ % OKと出力されない

\end{document}
```

`\csname`の使い方が間違っていますでしょうか？
ネットの情報はほとんどが`\expandafter\def\csname ... \endcsname`の例であり、`\csname`そのものの挙動について理解したいと思っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\csname...\endcsname` を使えば，スペースを含む制御綴を生成できます。よって，1.と3.では，`\anaconda␣` という制御綴が生成・使用されています。`\csname...\endcsname` の場合，存在しない制御綴が呼び出されても Undefined control sequence のエラーは出ず，`\relax` と同等に定義されます。

それに対し，2. の例では `\a` の後のスペースが制御綴直後のスペースということで消えるため，`\anaconda` という制御綴が意図通りに呼び出せています。

1.と3.においては，`a` の後のスペースを消せば，意図通りの動きをするでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
TeXの仕様を見返すと、`\csname...\endcsname`はカテゴリコード12以外のものでも入れることができるようですね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

これはつまり、\csname の挙動を理解するという問題というよりは、まずは TeX が読み込みファイル（文字コードの羅列）からトークン列を生成するプロセスについて理解する必要があるということですよね。
　この辺りの情報はウェブにはあまりないので、『The TeXbook』（邦訳は『TeXブック』）や『TeX by Topic』などの書籍を読むのが良いでしょう。（絶版のものもありますが、大学図書館などには入っていると思います）
ウェブでは「TeX Wiki」の「マクロの作成」というページに少し解説があります。
https://texwiki.texjp.org/?TeX%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80%2F%E3%83%9E%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90